# How to set the outline color of raster cell (pixel)?

Tags: raster, style

Can somebody please show me how to set the outline color of a raster cell (pixel)?
This is what I have right now:

[image]

This is what I am trying to do:

[image]

I [googled](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/123283/65002) a bit, and looks like it is somewhere in the `Layer->Properties->Style`, but I can not find it:

[image]

?

Comment: I don't think you can... you might want to convert your data to polygon (squares) and visualize them that way...

Comment: Thank you DPSSpatial. How can I convert the raster cells to polygons? And how to visualize them afterwards?

Comment: Under the Raster menu > Conversion > Polygonize... that should get you going...

Comment: Thank you DPSSpatial.
This is the result I got: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y5qhzi19vgls0x2/raster_polygonize.jpg?dl=0

It is interesting that the polygonization is done based on cell values (cells with the same values are grouped into a single polygon). Which is not what the upper photo shows. So there has to be a way to change the color of the raster cell's outline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe what you are asking can be done but an alternative solution is this:

1. Convert your raster data to points
2. Create a unique ID field and populate it with unique numbers
3. Convert your point dataset back to a raster using the unique ID as the value field
4. Convert this raster into a polygon vector dataset, as each cell in the raster has a unique value then the conversion from raster to vector will not cause the grouping of cells.
5. Display vector dataset over your original raster in what ever colour you desire.

I don't use QGIS but in ArcGIS there is a fishnet tool that could simplify the creation of the vector grid, so probably worth searching for such a tool in QGIS first?

Comment: Thank you @Hornbydd. Is it possible that not even ArcGIS does not have a simple option to edit the color of the outline of a raster cell (pixel)?

Comment: There is no functionality for displaying raster cell boundary in a different colour in arcmap